# Particle System Instances Retaining Dimensions of Original Object

Tags: particles

[image]

i have used a hair particle system to distribute the mesh on the bottom left as seen here. i want the particle system instances of this mesh to retain the same dimensions as the original mesh. ( i know for this simple example i can use an array modifier but i am showing a simplified situation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Particle System properties > Emission* > **Hair Length** 1
- *Particle System properties > Render* > **Scale** 1

[image]

Notes:

- If Hair length is set 2, than Render Scale should be 0.5, and so on to keep size equal.
- If dimension of source object is not 1 check also if *Particle System properties > Render > Object > Object Scale* is ON